# How to perform aggregation on sentiment values predictions and confidence

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

HI I hope you are doing well i want to perform aggregation query on sentiments but i get empty result i performing following query in kibana.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sentiment_stats": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sentiment.keywords"
      }
    },
    "total_predictions": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "predictions.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is the documents simple which is given below. I want to count the predictions aggregations. In predictions I have following category like Neutral, Negative positive etc

```
{
   "_source":{
      "id":"",
      "author":{
         "entity_type":"post",
         "username":"toyotapakistanofficial",
         "id":"toyotapakistanofficial",
         "name":"Toyota Pakistan",
         "url_c":"",
         "image":[
           
         ]
      },
      "target":{
         "entity_type":"page",
         "username":"toyotapakistanofficial",
         "id":"",
         "name":"Toyota Pakistan",
         "url":"",
         "image":"https://scontent.fisb1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-1/318613074_2269545816559690_2555827927620099181_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p200x200&_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5f2048&_nc_ohc=tFsWfA5qsO4AX8d8B0A&_nc_ht=scontent.fisb1-2.fna&cb_e2o_trans=q&oh=00_AfDLWo_btSY-atwX18C7IZeaIwKZAgBsxw85SONNZ_-nMg&oe=65613591",
         "url_c":""
      },
      "tags":"",
      "url_c":"https://www.facebook.com/toyotapakistanofficial/posts/pfbid02bdJaX7Vz1XdhZf4KaXEt5CFscjoeTcJouFDWT8MSQkPsZuu2evN3ZUnnbqdHCv2cl?__cft__[0]=AZUTQP6jV6SLsGP37O47XSD7GLxNbr5seDktH2r0_GIYgvFSQvm2Yds3sbTpYj2IdO3WTHSTz8kSmpmae2avdPKXdWlJoRm-IeFgj3QedewQVVOI2ACfjLcSA62fx6up2dptMCWPUTz4DEWu0t8euq75IJ0KzsL1qcyOQxi-sv6v5w7G2Xr_034ZOkIY7p8gZHg&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
      "associated_links":"",
      "headline":"",
      "timestamp_c":1693940400,
      "content_type":{
         "is_picture":true,
         "is_text":true,
         "is_video":false,
         "is_shared":false
      },
      "text_c":"Have you availed the Toyota Azaadi Deal yet?  ",
      "media_c":[
         
      ],
      "impressions":{
         "no_of_reactions_c":0,
         "no_of_comments_c":"12",
         "no_of_shares":"16"
      },
      "reactions":[
         
      ],
      "comments":[
         
      ],
      "shared_post":{
         "author":{
            
         },
         "content_type":{
            
         },
         "headline":"",
         "id":"",
         "media":[
            
         ],
         "target":{
            
         },
         "text":"",
         "timestamp":"",
         "url":"",
         "video_links":""
      },
      "target_information":{
         "target_type":"facebook",
         "target_subtype":"page",
         "GTR":"st_fb_21824",
         "CTR":"1",
         "uid":"7a587cfa-006c-4cf9-b604-bfe64d241e90",
         "username":"toyotapakistanofficial",
         "case_id":"1191"
      },
      "data_type":"facebook_page_posts",
      "kafka_id":"23a47ed3-e051-42fb-a145-5a4ff582eb93",
      "@timestamp":"2023-11-21 07:42:08",
      "Categories":{
         "confidence":[
            0.15142688155174255,
            0.6153247356414795
         ],
         "predictions":[
            "Economy"
         ]
      },
      "emotion":{
         "confidence":[
            "0.20653119683265686"
         ],
         "predictions":[
            "Indifferent"
         ]
      },
      "facial_id":"",
      "hashtags":[
         
      ],
      "mentions":[
         
      ],
      "ner":{
         "entities":[
            "Toyota Azaadi"
         ],
         "labels":[
            "PRODUCT"
         ]
      },
      "object_detection":[
         
      ],
      "sentiment":{
         "confidences":"",
         "predictions":[
            "Neutral"
         ],
         "confidence":[
            "0.4066358804702759"
         ]
      },
      "target_subtype":"",
      "target_type":"",
      "text_categories":{
         "confidences":"",
         "predictions":""
      },
      "topic":"",
      "valid":"",
      "weapon_detection":{
         "confidence":0.0,
         "is_weapon_detected":"",
         "predictions":"",
         "urls":""
      },
      "is_ai_applied":true,
      "sub_categories":{
         "predictions":[
            "Trade"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

can you tell me how to get predictions counts

Answer (score 1):

This can be related to **"size": 0**.

According to the official documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

```
size
(Optional, integer) Defines the number of hits to return. Defaults to 10.

By default, you cannot page through more than 10,000 hits using 
the from and size parameters. 
To page through more hits, use the search_after parameter.
```

Here is another source:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

Since I can not reproduce this on my local, I would recommend you to double check the aggregation with object and an array. Sentiment is an object while predictions is an array.